# Mysql: move specific records on top of the resultant array beside ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql

In mysql db table I have all countries like:

[image: countries_table]

and I fetched all countries as:

```
SELECT * FROM countries_table ORDER BY country_name
```

but I want to show some specific countries at top of the list:

[image: Specific Countries]

and then other will come in **ORDER BY country_name**

Could it be solved by **MYSQL** and/or **PHP** & how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a simple and not well-known MySQL trick:

```
SELECT * FROM countries_table
ORDER BY name = 'Australia' desc,
         name = 'UAE' desc,
         name = 'Pakistan' desc,
         name = 'UK' desc,
         name = 'USA' desc,
         name asc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [FIELD](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-order-specific-field-values/)

```
SELECT country_id, country_name 
FROM countries_table 
    ORDER BY 
FIELD(country_name, 'USA', 'UK', 'Pakistan', 'UAE', 'Australia') DESC,
country_name ASC
```

EDITED: thanks for [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903209/mysql-move-specific-records-on-top-of-the-resultant-array-beside-order-by/11903431#comment-15845407) [mvf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1555175/mvf)

Comment: In that case you should list "good" values in back order and add DESC after FIELD. Otherwise you will get listed values at the end of results in same order as listed. So the correct variant is

    SELECT country_id, country_name
        FROM countries_table
    ORDER BY 
        FIELD(country_name, 'USA', 'UK, 'Pakistan', 'UAE', 'Australia') DESC,
        country_name ASC;

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT country_id,
     country_name
FROM countries_table
ORDER BY (CASE country_name WHEN 'Australia' THEN '1'
                            WHEN 'UAE' THEN '2' 
                            ...
                            ELSE country_name 
          END) ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it, using `UNION`:

```
(SELECT * FROM countries_table
WHERE name IN('Australia', 'UAE', 'Pakistan', 'UK', 'USA')
ORDER BY name ASC)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM countries_table
WHERE name NOT IN('Australia', 'UAE', 'Pakistan', 'UK', 'USA')
ORDER BY name ASC)
```

Documentation: [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html)