# Sorted array with specific items on top using Zend_Db_Select order()

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

I am trying to modify a plug-in that, among other things, alphabetically sorts an array from a mysql database. The part of the relevant PHP file that does the sorting looks like this:

```
$select->order("$alias.name ASC");
```

I want to continue to sort the items in ascending order, but I want to keep a specific item at the top (out of its alphabetical order).

From the information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903209/mysql-move-specific-records-on-top-of-the-resultant-array-beside-order-by) it looks like the way to do this in MySQL would be simple, just:

```
ORDER BY name = 'Library' desc,
         name asc;
```

But even studying the information [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html), I can't quite translate this into the order() function. I have tried:

```
$select->order("$alias.name ='Library' DESC","$alias.name ASC")
```

But it seems that it does not work quite that way.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, found the answer-

I needed to use Zend_Db_Expr(). In case it is helpful to anyone else, this was solved like so:

```
$select->order(array(
    new Zend_Db_Expr("$alias.name = 'Library' DESC"),
    new Zend_Db_Expr("$alias.name ASC")
));
```